# How to reload parent page on open PopUp window in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

On a master page when use clicks on it a popup window is displayed using this code :

```
queryString = "web.aspx?ds=" + Base64ForUrlEncode(ds.ToString())        
newWin = "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(1200/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open('" + queryString +  ','_blank','height=700,width=1200,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\';'); window.opener.location.reload();";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
```

How to reload parent page on open PopUp window?

I have tried with

> window.opener.location.reload()

without success :

```
newWin = "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(1200/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open('" + queryString +  ','_blank','height=700,width=1200,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\';'); window.opener.location.reload();";
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You are already executing a server side code when opening the window and registering startupscript, hence you are doing a "reaload" of the page, I don't understand what you want or are trying to do.

Comment: @Esko Thank you fo reply, I need reload the parent page when I open PopUp window, because when open popup the parent page lost the css style.

Comment: I think you should find the real problem, why is the css-styles lost on postback instead of trying to bandaid the problem with a dirty fix. Anyway the reload you are trying to do is execyted on the parent page, when instead the ***window.opener.location.reload()*** should be executed on the ***child-page***

Answer (score 0):

Do you have you tried re-bind the parent page after open popup ?